# BIRT jdbc dataset. dynamic max row fetch

Tags: birt, rhino, fetch

BIRT report can limit the max row fetch size of a jdbc dataset within the dataset settings.
This is a manually entered Integer. I'm looking for a way to pass this dynamically from a ReportParameter to the jdbc dataset to limit the retrieved rows.

I prefer to do this e.g. in the beforeOpen() hook with JavaScript because setting the limit directly in the SQL is DBMS specific and I want the report to run on several DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, DB2, Sybase, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `beforeFactory()` hook:

```
reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findDataSet("Data Set").setRowFetchLimit(params["my_limit"].value);
```

Generally, a lot of beforeFactory() stuff starts with `reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle()`. You can find here any report element or even traverse all elements if necessary.

When you `find()` element, there are not all methods listed in a ctrl+space help. More contain Eclipse Help: *BIRT Programmer Reference -> Reference -> API Reference -> Report Object Model API Reference*. Class *Module Handle* is good place to start.

I'm not sure, if there is a shorter dot-chain to access report design handle. If so, please correct me.

Comment: +1 took me a while to understand and integrate this in my Report. Works perfectly!

Comment: reportcontext.getDesignHandle() should work as good as train wreck above